# Tool for finding common dependencies between sibling modules in Maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have to create a new maven project old projects migrated to maven. So I got a structure like this

```
parent
|
\-- project 1
|
\-- project 2
```

`project 1` and `project 2` have tons of dependencies and lots of them are common to each other. What I wonder, and I couldn't find in the internet, **is if there is a tool that I can find these common dependencies so I can migrate them to the parent pom?**

For examplo, if I provide to this tool two poms with elements like

```
... PROJECT 1 POM
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
       <artifcatId>A</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
       <artifcatId>B</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
...

.. PROJECT 2 POM
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
       <artifcatId>B</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
       <artifcatId>C</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

I want the output to be

```
.. OUTPUT FROM COMPARING BOTH
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
       <artifcatId>B</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Comment: I am not aware of such a tool which does this. However i can suggest you a workaround. List down dependencies of two projects and do a string comparison using a little java code or a shell script. For example.                                                                               
mvn -o dependency:list > deps1.txt,
mvn -o dependency:list > deps2.txt. You may have to do a grep and cut to filter duplicates and unwanted verbose

Comment: I was doing this using dependency:tree, but wanted to know if there's any tool that already does that for me. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Use the m2e plugin within Eclipse which supports refactoring of poms in that way.

Comment: IntelliJ Idea also supports this. Other than than I don't think there is a command-line tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know a tool that works like you described but there is a simple workaround:

Make a temporary third project and copy all dependencies from A and B to this pom. Than try to find duplicates with the [dependency:analyze-duplicate](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-duplicate-mojo.html) dependency-plugin goal like this:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-duplicate
```

You will get something like this

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building foobar 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-duplicate (default-cli) @ foobar ---
[INFO] List of duplicate dependencies defined in <dependencies/> in your pom.xml:
        o junit:junit:jar
```

To make sure that the duplicate really comes from both projects you should duplicate check the single projects on there own before.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know any tool to do it..but you can do it at old school

1.resolving all the dependencies : `mvn dependency:resolve`

2.List all the depencies sorted and with out repeting..and check module by module:

```
mvn -o dependency:list | grep ":.*:.*:.*" | cut -d] -f2- | sed 's/:[a-z]*$//g' | sort -u
```

3.then you can look for in all the modules

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections --> for example
```